# Create a subscription for the WP theme?

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I'm thinking of a way to make a php file from another server to run in my server...

For Example:

Server A contains:
call.php
file1.php
file2.php

Server B contains:
function.php

the code in call.php is

```
<?php require( 'serverBdomain.com/function.php' ); ?>
```

the code in function.php is

```
<?php
require( 'file1.php' );
require( 'file2.php' );
//other functions
?>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? because I'm working on a subscription based system wherein I can delete function.php so that the script in serverA won't run once subscription ends.

Thanks in advance

edit:
Thanks to all of those who posted answers and sorry for not being clear on my intentions. I think what I want to happen is not yet possible considering my current knowledge of php.

Here's the scenario, I created a subscription based wordpress theme and I wanted to disable the theme once the subscription of my client ends, my idea was moving the functions.php to my own server and prbably delete it so that the theme won't work anymore... Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: That's easy to circumvent. Users can just copy over the code and include it locally. This will continue to run after subscription ends. So what you suggest isn't really an option I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't do it. Ever.
You could read data with CURL and then parse it in PHP to read as PHP, but don't do it.
If you need to send data from one server to another, do it with something that is made for that, for example json_encode/decode.

If you want a more specific answer about that, you should make a more specific example - what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

You have to understand the difference between **the code** and **the data**.
The code is intended to process the data, not being data itself.

So, you have to populate some data with your subscription. 
The most common format is XML. Or, easier one - JSON

So, your server should output some JSON for example, and the remote server is going to just read it this way

```
<?php 
$rawdata = file_get_contents('http://serverBdomain.com/function.php?feed=id'); 
$data    = json_decode($rawdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's wrong way. Store all your files on one Server. You can protect your call.php, file1.php, file2.php placing them somewhere aside of user-base setting appropriate permissions, but all of that should be achieved on PHP level anyway. I would suggest you to learn [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html)

Answer (score -1):

After your edit - this is not a lively approach.

- First, no sane webmaster would include any outside code, as it's extremely dangerous. Especially it it's coming from such unexperienced user.
- Next, no sane webmaster would do a network lookup on each load - it will exhaust the bandwidth and make the site incredible slow.
- Finally, no sane webmaster would by *a subscription* for such a thing like a wp theme when there are thousands of free ones.

Comment: Sorry sir if I had the wrong approach..
I'll keep what you said in mind...

But the client that I had was asking me to create a theme specific for his needs, my client is not tech savvy so he doesn't know anything about wordpress so he can't go looking for a free theme...

Comment: so, it's sure a reason to pinch an unsuspicious simpleton.